# How to format word file using vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to insert a horizontal line with header and footer in the word file created using vb.net ?

How to add horizontal line and header/footer to the document using vb.net code ?

```
    Dim wa As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim wd As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim wp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
    'Dim section As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section
    Dim wp1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph

    wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    wa.Visible = False
    wd = wa.Documents.Add


    wp1 = wd.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    wp1.Range.Font.Bold = True
    wp1.Range.Text = DateTimePicker1.Text

    wp = wd.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    wp.Range.Text = TextBox1.Text + vbNewLine + TextBox2.Text
    wp.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    '  wp.Alignment.wdAlignParagraphDistribute()
    wd.SaveAs("g:\sample.docx")
    wa.Quit()
```